# jquery.validate focusCleanup on only some elements

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, focus

I need to use focusCleanup only on one or two elements of a form and not on each element. Is there a way to apply the focusCleanup in [jquery.validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to just a few of the input fields and not all of them? For example, I want to clean up input1 and input2 on focus but not input3. I tried adding the focusCleanup to the rules but that did not work. Any ideas?

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    focusCleanup: true,
    rules: {
        input1: {
            required: true,
        },
        input2: {
            required: true,
        },
        input3: {
            required: true,
        },
    },
    messages: {
        input1: {
            required: Messages.ERR_USERNAME_GUIDE,
        },
        input2: {
            required: Messages.ERR_PASSWORD_GUIDE,
        },
        input3: {
            required: Messages.ERR_PASSWORD_GUIDE,
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: Please review the answer below and accept it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no recommended way to do this in the [documented options for jquery validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), however you can achieve this by passing in your own onfocusin function as an option.

In the example below I give the elements that require no cleanup a class 'nocleanup'.  I have then copied the [default onfocusin method](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js#L220), inserting an if statement to check for the presence of this class.

html form excerpt

```
<input name="fname" id="fname" class="required">
<input name="sname" id="sname" class="required nocleanup">
<input name="other" id="other" class="required">
```

with validation code

```
$("form").validate({
    focusInvalid: false,
    focusCleanup: true,
    onfocusin: function (element, event) {
        this.lastActive = element;

        if (!$(element).hasClass("nocleanup")) {
            if (this.settings.focusCleanup && !this.blockFocusCleanup) {
                if (this.settings.unhighlight) {
                    this.settings.unhighlight.call(this, element, this.settings.errorClass, this.settings.validClass);
                }
                this.addWrapper(this.errorsFor(element)).hide();
            }
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
        alert('form ok');
    }
});
```

nb. the focusin is a straight copy of the [default focusin method](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js#L220), with just the addition of an if statement.

Try the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xaw5x/)